# How to generate function value based on attributes from left outer join relation for distinct rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table called `cars` which has many `images`.

I wanna return all distinct rows for `cars.id, cars.brand, (???some_query???) AS any_value_of_x_true`, where `any_value_of_x_true` is a virtual column generated by checking if any related rows in `images` table has `url = 'www.example.com'` AND `(images.data->'d'->>'x')::boolean IS TRUE`

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d50d84/3

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
id  brand any_value_of_x_true
1   Bmw   true
2   Audi  false
3   VW    false
```

PS. the real table has millions of rows, so it needs to be relatively good performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`bool_or`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-aggregate.html):

> **bool_or(expression)**
>
> true if at least one input value is true, otherwise false

```
SELECT cars.id, brand,
    bool_or(CASE WHEN url = 'www.example.com' 
             and (images.data->'d'->>'x') = 'true' THEN true else false end) 
             AS any_value_of_x_true

FROM cars
LEFT JOIN images on cars.id = images.car_id
GROUP BY cars.id, brand
ORDER BY id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d33e942167e990e0deedacbf854b6448)**

---

Without `CASE` as @Hans Z  proposed:

```
SELECT cars.id, brand, COALESCE(bool_or(url = 'www.example.com' 
                                and (images.data->'d'->>'x')::boolean), false)
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN images on cars.id = images.car_id
GROUP BY cars.id, brand
ORDER BY id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=620054708e3a5c5efa850a02f2c90ca9)**

**EDIT:**

Using `MAX` as @shawnt00 proposed:

```
SELECT cars.id, brand, 
max(case when url = 'www.example.com' and (images.data->'d'->>'x')::boolean 
     then 1 else 0 end
    )::boolean AS any_value_of_x_true
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN images on cars.id = images.car_id
GROUP BY cars.id, brand
ORDER BY id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo3](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=75524c8f8e22ba680d12eeb9143b1bec)**

Comment: `CASE WHEN (expr) THEN true ELSE false` is just equivalent to `(expr)`

Comment: @HansZ There is also NULL to handle http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fd70ba92652acaf238deb225a740a11a But I agree that case is not necessary

Comment: It might be better to explicitly handle that null check with a `bool_or(COALESCE(expr, false))`

Comment: Won't standard SQL work just as well? `max(case when ??condition?? then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: @shawnt00 Yes it will work too, but cast to boolean is needed